# Validate params based on condition in rails-grape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing APIs for a web app. In one specific case I am facing a situation where I require param2 only when value of param1 is false. I was able to use conditional statements to achieve it. I would like to know is there any inbuilt methods in grape for this type of validation. Something on the lines below

```
params do
 requires :model_name, type: Hash do
   optional :params1
   if params1 == false
     require :params2
   end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Also for more complex conditions, you can express this relationship through the given method

```
given params1: -> (params1) { params1 == false } do
  require :params2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need `mutually_exclusive` validation that ensures given params aren't present at the same time in a request

```
params do
 requires :model_name, type: Hash do
   optional :params1
   optional :params2
   mutually_exclusive :params1, :params2
 end
end
```

Grape supports it starting from [version 0.8.0](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#080-7102014)

There are also other options like `exactly_one_of`, `all_or_none_of`, `at_least_one_of`. [Read more](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#exactly_one_of)

Comment: Thanks Slava. But my request contains both the params. I am using ember.js for front end that  doesn't allow to pick and choose params to be sent to rails.